# How to convert vcproj to qt pro

Tags: qt, visual-c++

How can I convert vcproj to qt pro.
I do not have any Visual studio installed. And I don't have the disk space to install Visual Studio.
What should I do?

Comment: You don't need to convert anything. Simply write pro file from scratch.

Comment: There are no ways of importing vcproj in qtcreator . Or do you mean that I should copy all the header and cpp file and create a new project?

Comment: You do not have to copy any files, just create an empty *.pro file and type in your project data manually

Comment: @Freiza, I meant creating new pro file in a text editor. Just follow the tutorial for qmake.